# How To Create a Matte Car Paint Material?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, rendering

This is something that has been irking me for a while, as I've been working on a car project. I'm trying to create a paint (in cycles) similar to the the material in this image:

[image]

The problem is, whenever I try to make it, it always comes out looking to diffused or too sharp.

Here's my node setup:

[image]

And here's the render:

[image]

Comment: Show us a setup of your nodes and any results you have rendered, also realistic is too subjective and open to interpretation, can you specify a set style.. like chrome or matte.

Comment: To truly evaluate the material, use a pure white environment like your reference.

Comment: Haven't you made it a bit too glossy?

Comment: I'd like to see an answer with good explanations as to why each node is used, and how their values contribute to the resulting effect. And why changing certain control values change the result as they do.

Comment: Instead of mixing a bunch of glossy shaders, try mixing with a matte shader (diffuse or velvet). You can also play with using a fresnel as the mix factor. You'll probably just have to play around with the shader for a while to get something that looks nice.

Comment: What is the brand of the car on first image?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'm not completely sure what you are going after, but for an image like the top one lighting will be very important.

I don't have car model to demonstrate, but hopefully this gives you some ideas:

[image]

Material nodes:

[image]

If you want that paint fleck look that a lot of car paints have, try using a voronoi texture to modify the normals of a glossy shader underneath the main surface:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 8):

A matte car paint can be created with only five nodes:

- *Principled BSDF*
- *Velvet BSDF* or another *Principled BSDF*
- *Layer Weight*
- *Mix Shader*
- *Material Output*

---

**Material using Velvet BSDF for sheen**

[image: Matte car paint black using Velvet BSDF]
[image: Matte car paint white using Velvet BSDF]
<sub>The [BMW demo scene](https://www.blender.org/download/demo-files/) was create by Mike Pan</sub>

[image: Shader]

The *Principled BSDF* should have a *Roughness* between 0.3 and 0.5 depending on how matte the paint should be. I left all other parameters at their default, but the *Specular* value could be adjusted as well.

The *Velvet BSDF* in combination with the *Layer Weight* and *Mix Shader* nodes are the key to create the typical sheen of the matte car paint. The *Facing* output of the *Layer Weight* is used to blend between the *Principled BSDF* and *Velvet BSDF*.

---

**Material using Principled BSDF for sheen**

[image: Matte car paint black using Principled BSDF]

[image: Matte car paint black using Principled BSDF]
<sub>The [BMW demo scene](https://www.blender.org/download/demo-files/) was create by Mike Pan</sub>

[image: Shader]

In this variation the *Velvet BSDF* has been replaced by a *Principled BSDF*. The *Specular* parameter can be adjusted to control the amount of specular reflection in the areas with the sheen effect.

[image: Specular set to zero]
<sub>Specular set to zero for Principled BSDF with sheen</sub>

Comment: Why not to use Principled's sheen instead of Velvet? Is there something special about it?

Comment: @SergeL The *Velvet BSDF* looks different than the *Principled BSDF* with *Sheen*. For this use case it seemed to be closer to what I wanted to achieve. You could replace the *Velvet BSDF* with the *Principled BSDF*, but it would require a bit more parameter tweaking.   One benefit of using another *Principled BSDF* would be that the material works in Eeevee as well (which doesn't have the *Velvet BSDF*).

Comment: I've updated the answer. Personally I think the version with the *Velvet BSDF* looks better.

Comment: @brockmann No problem, still +150 points for me :)