# Trying to texure a formula 1 car,but i am a noob in cycles engine

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing

i have made a model of a formula 1 car, and now its time to put textures on it.

i want to make the entire body a single color,and then add the decals on top of it as a second "layer" of textures.

i watched a tutorial about basic cycles rendering,and from what i understand you can add multiple textures on a single material, connect them to a mix node, and after un wrapping they will both show as long as the "decal" has an alpha channel.

So i did all that, added a red base colour,and tried putting a "decal",but when i unwrap the decal is applied on all faces,not where i want to put it.

I tried creating 2 UV maps as suggested in a tutorial but it doesnt seem to work.

Could someone give me a step by step guide on how to do this,on a multifaced object (not on a single plane), and keep both the bottom and the top texture on the object?

Any help is much appreciated!

This is a pic of my model.

[image]

Comment: related : http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/61519/how-to-create-decal-from-mesh/61523#61523

Comment: Car paint material: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/182/how-to-create-a-matte-car-paint-material May be helpful.

Comment: thanks everyone for your help so far,i figured out that the texture i used as a decal was actually "tiling" and eventually just covered the botom texture. both the links you provided were very interesting and informative though,so i appreciate you linking them!