# Cycles - Glossy Object too dark, Background too bright

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, light, scene, lighting

I have set up a simple scene using a simple glossy material for my object, but, although the scene is enclosed and there is even a world background just in case, the object is way to dark compared to the background... If I increase the light drastically in order to achieve nice lighting on the object the background is nearly white.

How can I solve this?

Thank you,

Luca

[image]

Comment: Why are you using Velvet BSDF for this setup? Also try to connect Diffuse as first/top in Mix node.

Comment: It's hard to figure out what you are attempting to do. I would re-arrange the order of things: velvet and diffuse mix and the result gets then mixed (or added) with glossy. Also anytime you are dealing with glossy objects what matters is not the light on the object, but the surrounding environment that gets **reflected** on it. See: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/48659/why-does-an-object-with-a-glossy-shader-render-in-black/50576#50576 and do a search online for how to light and photograph cars. The trick is always in getting interesting reflections that reveal the shapes.

Comment: Car paint materials can be very complex. Read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/182/how-to-create-a-matte-car-paint-material and https://www.blendernation.com/2016/01/22/tutorial-realistic-car-paint-brdf-material/