# How to create car paint material?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, shaders

[image]

so i am trying to learn texturing so that i can render my cars, but these car paint materials are pretty hard to make for a noob. I did some research and tried making this shader in cycles but failed miserably. Can anyone help me here? How can i get car paint shader like one shown here in cycles?

Comment: Just google blender car paint material, there's plenty of resources on this topic already related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/182/how-to-create-a-matte-car-paint-material

Comment: i checked it but i didnt like the result

Comment: *didn't like* is definately to vague to produce a helpful answer for you. Try explaining, what you're trying to achieve. Apart from color, model and environment the materials in the linked question would help you achieve your result.

Answer (score 2):

Try this :D

Also, I suggest getting the PBR materials add-on if you want accurate materials.

[image]

Comment: Upvote for the simplicity, and the model K Noddycar.